# Is is possible to disable authentication providers for specific routes?

Tags: authentication, servicestack

We're evaluating service stack v.4.5.6.0 for a Web API and we want clients to be able to authenticate using basic auth or credentials but we do not want them to be able to provide a basic auth header in place of a JWT token or session cookie when using our services. While I realize this is somewhat arbitrary, is there a way to exclude routes from specific providers or force the use of a token/cookie to authenticate once they've logged in?

Auth config from AppHost:

```
private void ConfigureAuth(Container container)
{
    var appSettings = new AppSettings();              
    this.Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomAuthUserSession(),
         new IAuthProvider[]
          {
              new CredentialsAuthProvider(),
              new BasicAuthProvider(),
              new JwtAuthProvider(appSettings) 
          }) { IncludeAssignRoleServices = false, MaxLoginAttempts = 10} );

    var userRepository = new CustomUserAuthRepository(container.TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>());
    container.Register<IAuthRepository>(userRepository);

}
```

Comment: FYI see updated answer on new `session.AuthProvider` property which contains which AuthProvider was used to authenticate the user.

Comment: Thanks! the FromTokenCookie is working well for what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack lets you decide which AuthProviders you want your Services to be authenticated with, but it doesn't let you individually configure which adhoc AuthProviders applies to individual Services. Feel free to [add this a feature request](https://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests).

However if you want to ensure that a Service is only accessed via JWT you can add a check in your Services for `FromToken` which indicates the Session was populated by a JWT Token, e.g:

```
[Authenticate]
public class MyServices : Service
{
    public object Any(MyRequest request)
    {
        var session = base.SessionAs<AuthUserSession>();
        if (!session.FromToken)
            throw HttpError.Unauthorized("Requires JWT Authentication");

        //...
    }
}
```

From v4.5.7 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget) you can also use the new `session.AuthProvider` property which indicates what AuthProvider was used to Authenticate the user, e.g:

```
public object Any(MyRequest request)
{
    var session = base.SessionAs<AuthUserSession>();
    if (session.AuthProvider != JwtAuthProvider.Name)
        throw HttpError.Unauthorized("Requires JWT Authentication");

    //...
}
```

Refer to the docs for [different AuthProvider names for each AuthProvider](http://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#auth-provider-routes).